# How to hide a Snackbar and show a new one right after that?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I show a Snackbar indefinitely. If the Bluetooth gets turned off, I want to hide it and show a new one to tell the users that they have to turn on the bluetooth. I dismiss the previous Snackbar before showing the new one, but still only the old Snackbar stays visible.

```
activeSnackbar.dismiss();
Snackbar.make(parent, "Bluetooth is off", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Turn on", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    BluetoothUtil.enableBluetooth(main);
                }
            }).show()
```

How can I make the old Snackbar disappear before showing the new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special for it, just make the next Snackbar and show it, it will make the old one disappear without calling the dismiss method.